# Passing encoded url string containing %3A (colon) to an APEX page truncates everting after the last %3A

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I am using ORACLE APEX 5.0.1

I am passing an url string to an APEX application where I have encoded all special caracters, if there is one or more `%3A` (colon) in the url APEX seemes to truncate the value I am passing.
This affects only the last variable I am passing and only the remaining part after the last `%3A`, but if I place a `%3A` at the very end of the url it works  in APEX. 
I have asked about this in other forums and it seems to be a relative unknown issue in APEX, haven't got any relevant answer that explains the issue.

This example pass values to tre fields

```
"...../apex/f?p=118:32:::::P32_XX,P32_YY,P32_ZZ,:100030,486,VMKF%3AU%202012%3A50"
```

`P32_XX`, and `P32_YY` get the value ok
`P32_ZZ` only get the value `"VMKF:U 2012"`
but if I put a `%3A` at the end of the url like this

```
"...../apex/f?p=118:32:::::P32_XX,P32_YY,P32_ZZ,:100030,486,VMKF%3AU%202012%3A50%3A"
```

it works ok and `P32_ZZ` gets the value `"VMKF:U 2012:50".`

I have tested this in Windows Explorer 11, Google Crom and Mozilla Firefox (latest version) with the same behavior.

And I have the same behaviour if I use a literal colon (`:`)

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the colon is a separator for the different parts of the APEX URL.  I am surprised that using `%3F` doesn't fix it, but the solution is to surround the whole value by `\...\` like this:

```
...../apex/f?p=118:32:::::P32_XX,P32_YY,P32_ZZ,:100030,486,\VMKF%3AU%202012%3A50\
```

Note that you don't even need to escape the colons now:

```
...../apex/f?p=118:32:::::P32_XX,P32_YY,P32_ZZ,:100030,486,\VMKF:U%202012:50\
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test your proposal, but it seems like it's a bug in APEX. The problem occurs only in the last variable and only after the last% 3A (or :) is affected.